# header function mail() php

Tags: php, email, email-headers

i have to send mail with function mail() of PHP.
I have to insert Reply-To header but it not work:

```
<?php
    $body = "<html>\n";
    $body .= "<body style=\"font-family:Verdana, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#666666;\">\n";
    $body = $message;
    $body .= "</body>\n";
    $body .= "</html>\n";

    $headers  = "From: My site<noreply@example.com>\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: info@example.com\r\n";
    $headers .= "Return-Path: info@example.com\r\n";
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: Drupal\n";
    $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

    return mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $headers); ?>
```

In this example of php.net there is $headers .= "Reply-To: info@example.com\r\n"; but if copy and paste this and then send mail the Reply-To header there is not. If insert other header like From, CC, Bcc these there are correctly in my HTML mail, only Reply-To header there is not.
I have try like "Reply-to", "Reply to", "Reply To", "Reply" etc but it not work.
I have use Php 5.4 can help me?

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

add parameter for recipient, subject, and message.

then at this line 
    " return mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $headers); "

replace the $message into $body.

look like this

```
<?php

$recipient = "jack@example.com";
$subject = "test subject";
$message = "test message";
$body = "<html>\n";
$body .= "<body style=\"font-family:Verdana, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#666666;\">\n";
$body = $message;
$body .= "</body>\n";
$body .= "</html>\n";

$headers  = "From: My site<noreply@example.com>\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: info@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: info@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: Drupal\n";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

$result = mail($recipient, $subject, $body, $headers); 
var_dump($result);

?>
```

hope it will help you

Comment: Thanks for answer but the problem is not parameters...infact i have inizialize parameter recipient, subject and message and send correctly the mail.
When i open the mail i see in the field From "My site<noreply@example.com>" (like in this example), and if add $headers.="Cc: test@test.it\r\n" after  
$headers  = "From: My site<noreply@example.com>\r\n"; in the code when i open the mail i see in the field From "My site<noreply@example.com>" and in the field Cc test@test.it. Only the Reply-To header there is not. How can do for view correcly the field Reply-To in the mail?

Comment: I see.. But have you try to integrate the code I've given above to your code? I have tested my code and the reply to is showing. Let me know..