# How to catch bounced emails in PHP?

Tags: php, email, email-bounces

I want to save emails if it is bounced while sending email through PHP function mail() ? What is best way to catch that ?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011714/bounce-email-handling-with-php

Comment: check out my edited solution for code examples

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571806/bounced-mail-handling-in-php-any-up-to-date-solutions?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First you need to send email with mail() function with the use of additional headers. You point the return email address to a mailbox where you will gather the bounced emails. The below code is an example how to achieve that.

```
$recipient = "jack@someotherexample.com";
$subject = "test subject";
$message = "test message";

$body = "<html>\r\n";
$body .= "<body style=\"font-family:Verdana, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#666666;\">\r\n";
$body .= $message;
$body .= "</body>\r\n";
$body .= "</html>\r\n";

$headers  = "From: My site<noreply@example.com>\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: bounce@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: bounce@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP\r\n";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

$result = mail($recipient, $subject, $body, $headers); 

if($result)
{
    echo "email sent";
}
else
{
    echo "email send error";
}
```

[**SOURCE**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11610921/2596503)

Than you just check the inbox for bounced error emails. The below example code will connect to an imap inbox, fetch and print out all the emails it finds there. You can easily customise it to your needs.

```
/* connect to server */
$hostname = '{example.com:143}INBOX';
$username = 'bounce@example.com';
$password = 'password';

/* try to connect */
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to mailbox: ' . imap_last_error());

/* grab emails */
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');


/* if emails are returned, cycle through each... */
if($emails) {

  /* begin output var */
  $output = '';

  /* put the newest emails on top */
  rsort($emails);

  /* for every email... */
  foreach($emails as $email_number) {

    /* get information specific to this email */
    $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
    $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,1.2);

    /* output the email header information */
    $output.= '<div '.($overview[0]->seen ? 'read' : 'unread').'">';
    $output.= '<span>'.$overview[0]->subject.'</span> ';
    $output.= '<span>'.$overview[0]->from.'</span>';
    $output.= '<span>'.$overview[0]->date.'</span>';
    $output.= '</div>';

    /* output the email body */
    $output.= '<div class="body">'.$message.'</div>';
  }

  echo $output;
}

/* close the connection */
imap_close($inbox);
```

[**SOURCE**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5177772/2596503)

Comment: As far as I understand the `Return-Path` header will be overridden by the receiving mail server, so I am not sure if it makes any difference. https://www.sil0.io/post/mail-from-return-path-reply-to-bounce-address

Answer (score 0):

Add a bounce email address to the email header, and monitor that email account from PHP for bounces.

Comment: sorry i didn't get it, can you please write that with example code, Thanks in advance...